# Test wrapped expected exception inside a JUnit test method

Tags: java, exception, junit

I want to test that a certain exception is thrown with an `EOFException` as the exception cause in a certain part of a JUnit test method.

The test method itself is not supposed to throw an exception - just a specific part of it.

I accomplished it with:

```
...
try {
    MyClass.staticMethod();
} catch (MyException e) {
    Assert.assertEquals(e.getCause().getClass(), EOFException.class);
}
...
// other asserts
```

I was wondering if this is the best practice in such case, or there's a better way to do this, perhaps with some JUnit mechanism specific for exceptions (I read about `ExpectedException` but I understand it's for handling test methods that throw exceptions).

Comment: This is the best practice if you want to use JUnit without any external libraries. But you should have on test that verifies the correctness of the exception and another test that silently ignores the exception, but applies the other asserts.

Answer (score 1):

Version 2 of catch-exception library (currently in dev mode) allows you to use Lambda expressions and so you can also use static method calls.

```
catchException(() ->  MyClass.staticMethod());

assert caughtException() instanceof EOFException;
```

Comment: I do not test 2 behaviours. The exception is supposed to be thrown because I'm mocking the input of the method with a stream from a file. This assert is only to check that the method has finished because it reached the end of the file. This is irregular behavior of the method, but required for the test. The asserts that check the actual behavior I'm testing come later.

Comment: Oh, ok. I modified my response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library [Fishbowl](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/fishbowl).

```
...
Throwable e = exceptionThrownBy(() -> MyClass.staticMethod())
Assert.assertEquals(e.getCause().getClass(), EOFException.class);
...
//other asserts
```